# Cannot user "Select TOP @Count ..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a procedure something like below. it works fine when there is no "TOP @Count", or it works fine when i put a concrete vaule "TOP 100" .

So why i cannot pass the value there??? how can i walk around it???

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure    
    @Count int = 100
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT TOP @Count 
         t1.id AS ID, 
         t1.name AS Name, 
         t2.type AS TYPE    
    FROM sampleTable1 as t1 with (noloack), 
         sampleTable2 as t2 with (noloack)          
   WHERE (t1.t2Id = t2.Id)     
ORDER BY t1.name asc

END
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming 2005+, you need to use brackets:

```
  SELECT TOP (@Count) 
         t1.id AS ID, 
         t1.name AS Name, 
         t2.type AS TYPE
    FROM sampleTable1 as t1 with (noloack)
    JOIN sampleTable2 as t2 with (noloack) ON t2.id = t1.t2.id
ORDER BY t1.name
```

My understanding is the [bracket support was added in v2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) in order to not require [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: Wow.  I never knew this.  Thanks.